# sending an html email from php

Tags: php, html, email

I making a newsletter for my users and would like to send it using my php.
I use the mailer function which works fine. My problem is as follows.
the email does not appear as it should on gmail and hotmail and this only on the web version. If I use outlook or mail to view the email, then CSS is applied. but when i view the same email on the web, the css seems to be removed.
Any idea as to what I should be doing?

my second question is about the structure of the html email itself. should it have the html and body tags? or would just divs be enough? 
would you recommend using tables for the layout, as i have noticed some newsletters using them? maybe that is a better alternative to floats ( for html email only)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Google is your friend here, [This article seems to answer your question](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467).

Comment: If you have two questions: ask two questions.

Comment: source code always makes for a better question...

Comment: And to add a "this too" link: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E-Mail clients do not support the whole spectrum of HTML/CSS features that are supported by today’s web browsers.

See the following for further information:

- [Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org/)
- [Guide to CSS support in email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

Gmail's web UI strips all `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a completely self sufficient html document with styling included and all paths (links/images/etc...) should be complete paths.